# X key format in Morris Chart to be represent as DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: raphael, morris.js

Can a X axis format in Morris chart be changed from `YYYY-MM-DD` to `DD-MM-DD`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `xLabelFormat` function to achieve that:

```
xLabelFormat: function (d) {
    return ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d.getFullYear();
}
```

```js
Morris.Area({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { y: '2015-01-01', a: 1, b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-01-02', a: 2,  b: 3 },
    { y: '2015-01-02', a: 2,  b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-01-03', a: 1,  b: 4 },
    { y: '2015-01-04', a: 2,  b: 5 },
    { y: '2015-01-05', a: 3,  b: 3 },
    { y: '2015-01-06', a: 1, b: 2 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Individual Score', 'Team Score'],
  fillOpacity: 0.4,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  behaveLikeLine: true,
  resize: true,
  xLabelFormat: function (d) {
    return ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d.getFullYear();
  },
  pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
  pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
  lineColors: ['red', 'blue'],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I am using angular directive in which its not working                           <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div
         class="area-chart"
         area-chart 
           area-data='InfocenterInsightVm.infocenterCardTrail'
            area-xkey='date'
            area-ykeys='["count"]'
            area-labels='["Total Doctors Reach"]'
            area-colors='["#31C0BE"]',
            xLabelFormat: function (d) {
              return ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d.getFullYear();
            }
            >
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: I'm sorry, I never used angular. I don't think I can help you with that.

Comment: Can We use this thing for xKey instead of xLabel ?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal No you can't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @krlzlx
Actually My y axis fileds are datetime which looked weird on graph,
wanted to show them as date,
Now just changed my fields to date in Database.